# How to add picture tag in fotorama.js to load webp image in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, image

How to add picture tag in fororama.js to display the webP image.

Generally we wants to give control to browser to load the webp image based on the versions.

Please suggest if incase any alternate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Yireo_Webp2](https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/webp2) for adding WebP support in Magento 2. It changes all the img tags to picture tags and it also makes fotorama to use the webp images, if the browser supports it. The only problem with the module is that the method that they use to check the browser support didn't work in Firefox, so I override their has-webp.js and change the hasWebP function to the following:

```
return function hasWebP() {
    var kTestImages = {
        lossy: "UklGRiIAAABXRUJQVlA4IBYAAAAwAQCdASoBAAEADsD+JaQAA3AAAAAA",
        lossless: "UklGRhoAAABXRUJQVlA4TA0AAAAvAAAAEAcQERGIiP4HAA==",
        alpha: "UklGRkoAAABXRUJQVlA4WAoAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAQUxQSAwAAAARBxAR/Q9ERP8DAABWUDggGAAAABQBAJ0BKgEAAQAAAP4AAA3AAP7mtQAAAA==",
        animation: "UklGRlIAAABXRUJQVlA4WAoAAAASAAAAAAAAAAAAQU5JTQYAAAD/////AABBTk1GJgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGQAAABWUDhMDQAAAC8AAAAQBxAREYiI/gcA"
    };
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "data:image/webp;base64," + kTestImages['lossy'];
    return (img.width > 0) && (img.height > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, now I use Fotorama like this:

```
<div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs">
        <a href="/file-1.jpg">
                <picture>
                        <source srcset="/file-1_thumb.webp" type="image/webp" />
                        <img src="/file-1_thumb.jpg" />
                </picture>
        </a>
        <a href="/file-2.jpg">
                <picture>
                        <source srcset="/file-2_thumb.webp" type="image/webp" />
                        <img src="/file-2_thumb.jpg" />
                </picture>
        </a>
</div>
```